# multiple variables in mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, database-trigger

Please check the trigger below :

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER shop_balance_insert AFTER INSERT ON shop_transfers
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

DECLARE PROD_CODE VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE  SUBCAT_ID  INTEGER;
    DECLARE  COLOR_ID  INTEGER;
    DECLARE  SIZE_ID  INTEGER;

    SELECT product_code,subcat_id,color_id,size_id    INTO  PROD_CODE,SUBCAT_ID,COLOR_ID,SIZE_ID FROM inventories WHERE bar_code =NEW.barcode     LIMIT 0,1;

    INSERT INTO shop_product_balance(product_code, subcat_id,color_id,size_id  ,barcode,shop_id,tbl_name,tbl_date,tbl_primary_key,trns_to_qty,trns_from_qty,sold_qty,return_qty, trnsStatus_st) VALUES
    (PROD_CODE, SUBCAT_ID ,COLOR_ID , SIZE_ID, NEW.barcode, NEW.tshopID,'shop_transfers', NEW.trnsDT, NEW.transferID, NEW.qty,0,0,0,0);

    INSERT INTO shop_product_balance(product_code, subcat_id,color_id,size_id  ,barcode,shop_id,tbl_name,tbl_date,tbl_primary_key,trns_to_qty,trns_from_qty,sold_qty,return_qty, trnsStatus_st) VALUES
    (PROD_CODE, SUBCAT_ID,COLOR_ID , SIZE_ID ,NEW.barcode, NEW.fshopID,'shop_transfers', NEW.trnsDT, NEW.transferID,0, NEW.qty,0,0,1);  

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

The trigger worked fine until there was only single variable  PROD_CODE.I recently added the other three -subcat,size,color.
But now - values for the new three columns (subcat,size,color) are not showing in table.Other column values are working fine.

[N.B : The datatype for the columns are the same as declared here int]

Did I make any mistake while declaring or setting variables.

Comment: `FROM inventories WHERE bar_code =NEW.barcode LIMIT 0,1` Why you use `LIMIT` here? query may return more than 1 rows? if yes, then may be you need use `ORDER BY` for explicit sorting ?

Comment: no ,the query returns only 1 row.I just used limit for no reason

Comment: Don't use the same name for columns,declared variables and parameters.